# jQuery Autocomplete: On select parse other key from the same array

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete snippet which retrieve's City names based on your search term.

For example the search term `s` would print:

[image]

So if I would use:

```
var f = [];
$.each(a.RESULTS, function (a, b) {
    f.push(b.name /* + b.zmw */)
});
b(f)
```

I would get printed the `name` of every city.

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/muWah/18/

**How could I print/console.log() the `zmw` value of each city whenever I click on it.**

So when I click on `Serbia`, I should get printed `000RB.1.99999`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.each(a.RESULTS, function (a, b) {
   f.push({label: b.name, value : b.zmw})
});
```

You can push a new object, with a label and value. 
Label is what's picked up for auto-complete, and value is what appears in the input when selected.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/muWah/21/

If you wanted to just have the `zmw` reference in the console, rather than printed out in the input, you can add more properties to the object you passed through. For example:

```
$.each(a.RESULTS, function (a, b) {
    f.push({label: b.name, value : b.name, zmw : b.zmw})
});
```

Then `b.item.zmw` would be what you'd print out in your console, but the name/value would still be `"Serbia"` (or whatever you click on)

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/muWah/24/